# Stats object from Get-Stats does not match the "-Start" parameter: PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware, powershell-3.0, powercli

I am working on a script to pull VM memory ballooning and ready summation statistics. I want to pull 24 hours worth of stats at 5 minute intervals. The command I run is:

```
$datetime = Get-Date       #Get the datetime it currently is
$date = $datetime.Date     #Get just the date, starting at midnight
$interval = 5
$statType = "mem.vmmemctl.average", "cpu.ready.summation"

$vmStats = get-stat -Entity $vm -start $date.AddDays(-1) -Finish $date -MaxSamples 10000 -stat $statType -IntervalMins $interval
```

However, the results of this give a set of stats that go up to `$date` (midnight of today), but only go as far back as a *rounded current time of day*, yesterday.

For example, if `get-date` returns `03/14/2018 10:43:42 AM`, and `$date` is set to `03/14/2018 12:00:00 AM` the earliest stat returned when a start date of `$date.AddDays(-1)` is used is `2018-03-13 10:30:00.000`.

I do not know what is happening. I have tried casting both `$date` and `$date.AddDays(-1)` as `[date]` and `[datetime]`, and I have also tried hardcoding midnight values as the start and finish date. Nothing seems to change the fact that the earliest stat is based on the time of day that `Get-Stat` was executed.

This does not happen when 30 minute or 2 hour intervals are used. The issue seems to happen only with 5 minute intervals for stats. What am I doing wrong? Is this the normal behavior of `Get-Stat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5-minute granularity you want is only available for the past 24 hours. Stats older than that are rolled up into the 30-minute intervals you observe (and eventually rolled up further).

[Archived stats](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-5230)

> "are aggregations (rollups) of the  real-time stats. They are
>   aggregated at different sampling intervals and  stored in the
>   database. We follow the MRTG standard.
>
> Past day: past day stats take the real-time stats and roll  them up so that there is 1 data point for every 5 minutes. Thus, there  are
>   12 data points per hour and 288 per day.
>
> Past week: past week stats take the past day stats and roll  them up so that there is 1 data point for every 30 minutes. Thus, there 
>   are 48 data points per day and 336 per week.
>
> Past month: past month stats take the past week stats and  roll them up so there is 1 data point per 2 hours. Thus, there are 12  data
>   points per day and 360 per month (30-day month).
>       Past year: past year stats take the past month stats and roll  them up so there is 1 data point per day. Thus, there are 365 data 
>   points per year."

Comment: Thank you, I had a hunch that something was happening that was causing the stats to simply not exist to be retrieved by get-stats. I didn't know that the roll-ups happened that frequently and that the granular stats became unavailable after that point.